# Is it possible to define the width of a dialog popup?

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently working on some Blender python exercises to expand my knowledge, my first project is to get a dialog popup to apply modifiers to specific object groups to speed up my workflow.

Everything currently works, however I have one issue with the dialog dimensions. It appears to stay the same size horizontally, no matter the content. This results in clipping etc.

[image]

Is there some way to either **a)** define an exact size (undesireable) or **b)** make it adjust to contain all content.

Comment: is it an `invoke_props_dialogue`?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes it is

Comment: For the _undesirable_ exact size `WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog(operator, width=300, height=20)` set the width.

Comment: @batFINGER and in case it isn't an `invoke_props_dialogue` but a simple redo panel?

Comment: AFAIK can't be set, defaults to fit content. As mentioned prior consider not using an operator and set preference properties directly from a panel. (Can even popup a panel in 2.8*)

Comment: @batFINGER `WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog(operator, width=300, height=20)` gives error `TypeError: WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog(): takes at most 2 arguments, got 3`. And if I use only `height` it says `TypeError: WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog(): was called with invalid keyword argument(s) (heigt), expected (operator, width)`. So it gets only `width`!!!

Comment: Use an instance `context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog()`  It is common in python documentation  to show a method / property  on the class it is defined for like `bpy.types.Object.location`  Congratulations on finding it now only uses width, makes sense since height is defined by content. has changed, https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog  Consult the latest docs for latest changes. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog